Salesforce Data Cloud - Cannot edit object permissions for Data Stream Object

Hey Guy's, I was using a trial org to complete the Salesforce Data Cloud certification in the Partner Learning Community. I had this task of ingesting data from Service Cloud using a Standard Data Bundle. For the same, I had to edit permission for the CRM Connector permission Set but it is showing this error below. What should I do?
